# C-To-MASM Conversion

Tags: assembly, masm

I've been reading "Assembly Language: A Concise Introduction" for some time now and there is an exercise question, regarding the conversion of the following C program

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()  
{
    int voltage;   

    printf("%s", "Enter an AC Voltage: ");
    scanf("%d", &voltage);

    if (voltage >= 110 && voltage <= 120)
        printf("\n%s\n", "Voltage is Acceptable");

    else 
    {
        printf("\n%s\n","Warning!");

        if (voltage < 110)
            printf("%s\n","Voltage too Low"); 
        else
            printf("%s\n","Voltage too High");
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my effort so far

```
    .386

.MODEL flat, c

printf PROTO arg1:Ptr BYTE, printlist:VARARG
scanf  PROTO arg2:Ptr BYTE, inputlist:VARARG

.DATA
    msgfmt1 BYTE "%s", 0
    msgfmt2 BYTE "%d", 0
    msgfmt3 BYTE "%c", 0
    msgfmt4 BYTE 0Ah, "%s", 0Ah, 0
    msgfmt5 BYTE "%s", 0Ah, 0

    msg1 BYTE "Enter an AC Voltage: ", 0
    msg2 BYTE "Voltage is Acceptable", 0
    msg3 BYTE "Warning!", 0
    msg4 BYTE "Voltage too Low!", 0
    msg5 BYTE "Voltage too High!", 0

    nl EQU 0Ah

    voltage SWORD ?

.CODE
    _Prog PROC  
        INVOKE printf, ADDR msgfmt1, ADDR msg1 
        INVOKE scanf, ADDR msgfmt2, ADDR voltage 

        if01: 
            CMP voltage, 110
            JL else01 
            CMP voltage, 120
            JG else01
            INVOKE printf, ADDR msgfmt4, ADDR msg2
            JMP endif01

        else01: 
             INVOKE printf, ADDR msgfmt4, ADDR msg3 

             if02: 
                 CMP voltage, 110
                 JGE else02
                 INVOKE printf, ADDR msgfmt5, ADDR msg4
                 JMP endif02     
             else02: 
                 INVOKE printf, ADDR msgfmt5, ADDR msg5
                 JMP endif02            
        endif02: 
        endif01: 
        RET
    _Prog ENDP
END
```

So, i would like to ask, does the above MASM program correctly implements the C equivalent? 
If so, what optimizations are available? And finally, what are the implications of *not* using the high-level features which some assembly flavours provide (like .if and .else directives)?

P.S. AFAIU, after some testing, the only missing element is the final newline, but i'll eventually add it.

Comment: To determine equivalence, devise some tests that you can run on the C program, then on the ASM program and compare results. Based upon what this C program looks like, it should be pretty straight forward. The "high level" feature that benefits you the most in this case is `INVOKE`. Without it, you need to know the parameter/stack convention of the routines you're calling and provide them explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible optimization of this program is for size. To optimize for speed is meaningless, because there is no iterations. The program is too simple. So, try to make it smaller. Although even this is not so simple, because of the simplicity of the program. But you can try to optimize the string constants - for example there are 4 times "Voltage" string defined.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, JohnFound. Yes, i will probably reduce the number of occurances of Voltage.